# Не открывается изображение для обрезки Jcrop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт когда пытаюсь сделать превью то превю фото не открывается, но если готовое фото вставить то все работает по ссылке то есть так  но новые фото все так же не показваются  хотя в консоли браузера грузятся вот код

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {

      $('#target').show();

      $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#photo").change(function() {
  readURL(this);

});



var x1, y1, x2, y2, crop = 'crop/';
var jcrop_api;
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#target').Jcrop({
    onChange: showCoords,
    onSelect: showCoords
  }, function() {
    jcrop_api = this;
  });
  // Снять выделение 
  $('#release').click(function(e) {
    release();
  });
  // Соблюдать пропорции 
  $('#ar_lock').change(function(e) {
    jcrop_api.setOptions(this.checked ? {
      aspectRatio: 4 / 3
    } : {
      aspectRatio: 0
    });
    jcrop_api.focus();
  });
  // Установка  минимальной/максимальной ширины и высоты
  $('#size_lock').change(function(e) {
    jcrop_api.setOptions(this.checked ? {
      minSize: [80, 80],
      maxSize: [350, 350]
    } : {
      minSize: [0, 0],
      maxSize: [0, 0]
    });
    jcrop_api.focus();
  });
  // Изменение координат 
  function showCoords(c) {
    x1 = c.x;
    $('#x1').val(c.x);
    y1 = c.y;
    $('#y1').val(c.y);
    x2 = c.x2;
    $('#x2').val(c.x2);
    y2 = c.y2;
    $('#y2').val(c.y2);
    $('#w').val(c.w);
    $('#h').val(c.h);
    if (c.w > 0 && c.h > 0) {
      $('#crop').show();
    } else {
      $('#crop').hide();
    }
  }
});

function release() {
  jcrop_api.release();
  $('#crop').hide();
}
// Обрезка изображение и вывод результата
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#crop').click(function(e) {
    var img = $('#target').attr('src');
    $.post('action.php', {
      'x1': x1,
      'x2': x2,
      'y1': y1,
      'y2': y2,
      'img': img,
      'crop': crop
    }, function(file) {
      $('#cropresult').append('<img  src="' + crop + file + '" class="mini">');
      release();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* jquery.Jcrop.css v0.9.12 - MIT License */
/*
  The outer-most container in a typical Jcrop instance
  If you are having difficulty with formatting related to styles
  on a parent element, place any fixes here or in a like selector

  You can also style this element if you want to add a border, etc
  A better method for styling can be seen below with .jcrop-light
  (Add a class to the holder and style elements for that extended class)
*/
.jcrop-holder {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: left;
}
/* Selection Border */
.jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff url("Jcrop.gif");
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.jcrop-vline {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px !important;
}
.jcrop-vline.right {
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-hline {
  height: 1px !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.jcrop-hline.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
/* Invisible click targets */
.jcrop-tracker {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* "turn off" link highlight */
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* disable callout, image save panel */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* disable cut copy paste */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
/* Selection Handles */
.jcrop-handle {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 1px #eeeeee solid;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  font-size: 1px;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-n {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-s {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-e {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-w {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 50%;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-nw {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-ne {
  margin-right: -4px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-se {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-right: -4px;
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-handle.ord-sw {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
/* Dragbars */
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n,
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s {
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e,
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w {
  height: 100%;
  width: 7px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n {
  margin-top: -4px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e {
  margin-right: -4px;
  right: 0;
}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
/* The "jcrop-light" class/extension */
.jcrop-light .jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-light .jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70) !important;
  opacity: .70!important;
}
.jcrop-light .jcrop-handle {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* The "jcrop-dark" class/extension */
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-vline,
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-hline {
  background: #000000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70) !important;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-handle {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
/* Simple macro to turn off the antlines */
.solid-line .jcrop-vline,
.solid-line .jcrop-hline {
  background: #ffffff;
}
/* Fix for twitter bootstrap et al. */
.jcrop-holder img,
img.jcrop-preview {
  max-width: none;
}

#sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
}
i.fa.fa-cog.fa-spin.fa-5x.fa-fw {
    font-size: 20vw;
}
.address_check {
    font-size: 1vw;
        padding-bottom: 1vw;
}
.info-check {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#hideModal{
    display: none;
}
#showFemale{
    display: none;
}
#showMale{
    display: none;
}
i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o {
    float: right;
}
.btn-group.mr-2 {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
.prace-check {
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0px;
    border-style: dashed;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    background-color: rgba(237, 237, 29, 0.36);
    padding: initial;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}



.logo-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.row.formBorder {
    border: 1px solid rgb(30, 190, 190);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.row.formBorder:hover{
   cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;   
}
.name_object_check {
    color: black;
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#sidebar .list-group-item {
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    color: #535c69!important;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    /* border-color: #333333; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}
strong.color-blue {
    color: #36b5df;
}
div#preview {
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
}
i.fa.fa-at {
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
i.fa.fa-mobile{
    font-size: 2vw;
    font-weight: inherit;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
.col-md-7.fullContactCompany.buttom-check-emp {
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
}
.fullContactCompany {
font-style: inherit;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border: 1px solid #36b5df;
    text-align: start;padding: 6px;
        font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
line-height: 2vw;
border-radius: 27px;
margin-top: 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.fullContactCompanyEmployees{
        font-style: inherit;
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border: 1px solid #36b5df;
    text-align: start;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    border-radius: 27px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
.deportament {
    display: inline-table;
    background: #36b5df;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0275d8;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.deportament:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px black;
}
p a.btn.btn-primary {
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
    width: 100%;
}
.classImg{
height: 116px; 
position: relative; 
max-width: 175px;
}
.classImg img{
position: absolute; 
margin: auto; 
left: 0; 
top: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
right: 0; 
width: 145px;
    max-height: 75px;
}
.deportamentLink{
color: white;
}
.deportamentLink:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
li.nav-item {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
i.fa.fa-times {
  
    color: red;
    float: right;

}
strong.color-white {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.fileprew {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.fileprew img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
#fileprewtwo {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#fileprewtwo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
.preview {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.preview img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
.previewtwo {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.previewtwo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;

}
.file_upload_two {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 1.65;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    width: 95px;
    top: 96px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 32vw;
    margin-left: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.18);
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: rgb(30, 190, 190);
    text-shadow: -1px 0px 2px black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.file_upload_two:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px #6a6666;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
.file_upload_two input[type=file] {
  position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    line-height: 0px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#image{
  display: none;
}
.file_upload_two input[type=file]:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
  }

#timedisplay {
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: "OpenSans-Light",sans-serif;
    height: 63px;
    line-height: 39px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    z-index: 5;
    float: right;
}
a.menuCompanyEmployees {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding: 0 15px 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #36b5df;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
a.menuCompanyEmployees:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px black;
}
button.btn.btn-info.dropdown-toggle {
    background: #36b5df;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
}
button.btn.btn-info.dropdown-toggle:hover {
   box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
 }
 i.fa.fa-bell-o {
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 31px;
}
i.problems {
    font-style: initial;
    background-color: tomato;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
}
.bg-color {
    padding-top: 1.5vw;
    background-color: #535c69;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
/* highlight active menu */

i.fa.fa-toggle-on.fa-lg.col-xs-1 {
    color: #36b5df;
    margin-top: 12px;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
button.btn.btn-info.dropdown-toggle:active {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* KHTML */
  border-radius: 10px; 

}
/* closed state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* open state */
#sidebar .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

/* level 1*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse .list-group-item  {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

/* level 2*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* level 3*/
#sidebar .list-group .collapse > .collapse > .collapse .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.input-file-row-1:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
.input-group{
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-width: 1px 0px 1px 1px;
  background-color: #717a84;
  border: 0;
}
.input-group:focus{
  background-color: #fff;
}
.form-control{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #717a84;
    border: 0;
}
button.btn.btn-secondary {
    background: #717a84;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #999999;
}
.btn.active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
.input-file-row-1{
    display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

html[xmlns] .input-file-row-1{
    display: block;
}

* html .input-file-row-1 {
    height: 1%;
}

.upload-file-container { 
  position: relative;
    width: 274px;
    height: 203px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 -27px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
        right: 8px;
    margin-left: 23px;
} 
#hideAvatar {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    right: 8px;
    background-image: url(../img/avatar.jpg);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    width: 13vw;
    height: 13vw;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    left: 30px;
    top: -22px;
}
#hideAvatar:hover{
background-blend-mode: luminosity;
background-color: tomato;
cursor: pointer;
content: "scsd";
color: black;
}
.upload-file-container:first-child { 
  margin-left: 0;
} 

.upload-file-container > img {
    width: 44vw;
    height: auto;
}

.upload-file-container-text{
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #719d2b;
  line-height: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 35px;
}


.file_upload {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 1.65;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    width: 95px;
    top: 96px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 17vw;
    margin-left: 14px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.18);
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: rgb(30, 190, 190);
    text-shadow: -1px 0px 2px black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
 .file_upload:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px #6a6666;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
.file_upload input[type=file] {
  position: relative;
    top: -40px;
    line-height: 0px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#target{
  
      width: 43.7vw;
}
.file_upload input[type=file]:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
  }
.bg-field{
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#position{
     background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#act{
     background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#specialization{
     background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#property_type{
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#the_property{
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#material{
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
select#area{
    background-color: #eef2f4;
    border-color: #36b5df;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;  
}
button#multi-post {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 20px; */
    width: 95px;
    top: 96px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin-left: 14px; */
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.18);
    color: #efefef;
    background-color: rgb(30, 190, 190);
    text-shadow: -1px 0px 2px black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
}
.bg-danger {
    color: #fff!important;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: #d9534f!important;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
i.fa.fa-cog {
    float: right;
    color: #535c69;
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.25,1);
    font-size: 2vw;
    padding-top: 15px;;;;
}
i.fa.fa-cog:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-title {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.modal-header {
    padding: 10px 20px 15px 20px;
}
.modal-header .close {
    margin-top: -18px;
}
@media (max-width:48em) {
    /* overlay sub levels on small screens */
    #sidebar .list-group .collapse.in, #sidebar .list-group .collapsing {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 190px;
    }
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item {
        text-align: center;
        padding: .75rem .5rem;
        min-width: 39px;
    }
    /* hide caret icons of top level when collapsed */
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"]::after,
    #sidebar .list-group > .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"]::after {
        display:none;
    }
    .page-header.col-md-5.col-xs-12 {
    margin: 10px 0 12px 0;
}
.padingUp {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}
}

/* change transition animation to width when entire sidebar is toggled */
#sidebar.collapse {
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
          transition-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
       -o-transition-duration: .2s;
          transition-duration: .2s;
}

#sidebar.collapsing {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
       -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
          transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-property: width;
       -o-transition-property: width;
          transition-property: width;

}
.avatar {
    background-color: #333333;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}
.ajax-file-upload-statusbar {
border: 1px solid #0ba1b5;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 420px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px
}

.ajax-file-upload-filename {
width: 300px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0px;

}

.ajax-file-upload-filesize {
width: 50px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ajax-file-upload-progress {
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
position: relative;
width: 250px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 1px;
border-radius: 3px;
display: inline-block;
color:#FFFFFF;

}
.ajax-file-upload-bar {
background-color: #0ba1b5;
width: 0;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 3px;
color:#FFFFFF;

}
.ajax-file-upload-percent {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 3px;
left: 48%
}
.ajax-file-upload-red {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
box-shadow: inset 0 39px 0 -24px #e67a73;
background-color: #e4685d;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 4px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #b23e35;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
.ajax-file-upload-green {
background-color: #77b55a;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: normal;
padding: 4px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #5b8a3c;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 5px 10px 5px 0px;
}
.ajax-file-upload {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor:pointer;
  line-height:20px;
  height:25px;
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  color: #888;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #e8e8e8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #e8e8e8;
  padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f8ab9;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #13648d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #13648d;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #13648d;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }

.ajax-file-upload:hover {
      background: #3396c9;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #15719f;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #15719f;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 #15719f;
}

.ajax-upload-dragdrop
{

  border:2px dotted #A5A5C7;
  width:420px;
  color: #DADCE3;
  text-align:left;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.state-hover
{
    border:2px solid #A5A5C7;
}
.ajax-file-upload-container
{
  margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rl76.online/crm/tapmodo/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<div class="input-file-row-1">


  <img src="" id="target" alt="[Jcrop Example]" onchange="previewFiles()" />
  <button id="release">Убрать выделение</button>
  <button id="crop">Обрезать</button>
  <div class="optlist offset">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="ar_lock" />Соблюдать пропорции (4:3)</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="size_lock" />min/max размер (80x80/350x350)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-labels">
    <label>X1 <input type="text" size="4" id="x1" name="x1" /></label>
    <label>Y1 <input type="text" size="4" id="y1" name="y1" /></label>
    <label>X2 <input type="text" size="4" id="x2" name="x2" /></label>
    <label>Y2 <input type="text" size="4" id="y2" name="y2" /></label>
    <label>W <input type="text" size="4" id="w" name="w" /></label>
    <label>H <input type="text" size="4" id="h" name="h" /></label>
  </div>
  <p>Результаты:</p>
  <div id="cropresult"></div>
  <div class="upload-file-container-text">



  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="file_upload"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Добавить<input type="file" name="photo" class="photo" id="photo" />
  </div>
</div>
```

единственное у меня нет черного прямоугольника

Comment: при добавление     init: function(core){
      this.core = core;
 } картинка показывается но нельзя обрезать

Answer (score 0):

Вот уже в который раз сам лично нашел [ответ на вопрос](https://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-image-uploader-with-jcrop/) с тем условие, что подключена библиотека `Jcrop.JS`:

```js
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB'];
    if (bytes == 0) return 'n/a';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return (bytes / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(1) + ' ' + sizes[i];
};

// check for selected crop region
function checkForm() {
    if (parseInt($('#w').val())) return true;
    $('.error').html('Please select a crop region and then press Upload').show();
    return false;
};

// update info by cropping (onChange and onSelect events handler)
function updateInfo(e) {
    $('#x1').val(e.x);
    $('#y1').val(e.y);
    $('#x2').val(e.x2);
    $('#y2').val(e.y2);
    $('#w').val(e.w);
    $('#h').val(e.h);
};

// clear info by cropping (onRelease event handler)
function clearInfo() {
    $('.info #w').val('');
    $('.info #h').val('');
};

// Create variables (in this scope) to hold the Jcrop API and image size
var jcrop_api, boundx, boundy;

function fileSelectHandler() {

    // get selected file
    var oFile = $('#image_file')[0].files[0];

    // hide all errors
    $('.error').hide();

    // check for image type (jpg and png are allowed)
    var rFilter = /^(image\/jpeg|image\/png)$/i;
    if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
        $('.error').html('Please select a valid image file (jpg and png are allowed)').show();
        return;
    }

    // check for file size
    if (oFile.size > 250 * 1024) {
        $('.error').html('You have selected too big file, please select a one smaller image file').show();
        return;
    }

    // preview element
    var oImage = document.getElementById('preview');

    // prepare HTML5 FileReader
    var oReader = new FileReader();
        oReader.onload = function(e) {

        // e.target.result contains the DataURL which we can use as a source of the image
        oImage.src = e.target.result;
        oImage.onload = function () { // onload event handler

            // display step 2
            $('.step2').fadeIn(500);

            // display some basic image info
            var sResultFileSize = bytesToSize(oFile.size);
            $('#filesize').val(sResultFileSize);
            $('#filetype').val(oFile.type);
            $('#filedim').val(oImage.naturalWidth + ' x ' + oImage.naturalHeight);

            // destroy Jcrop if it is existed
            if (typeof jcrop_api != 'undefined') {
                jcrop_api.destroy();
                jcrop_api = null;
                $('#preview').width(oImage.naturalWidth);
                $('#preview').height(oImage.naturalHeight);
            }

            setTimeout(function(){
                // initialize Jcrop
                $('#preview').Jcrop({
                    minSize: [32, 32], // min crop size
                    aspectRatio : 1, // keep aspect ratio 1:1
                    bgFade: true, // use fade effect
                    bgOpacity: .3, // fade opacity
                    onChange: updateInfo,
                    onSelect: updateInfo,
                    onRelease: clearInfo
                }, function(){

                    // use the Jcrop API to get the real image size
                    var bounds = this.getBounds();
                    boundx = bounds[0];
                    boundy = bounds[1];

                    // Store the Jcrop API in the jcrop_api variable
                    jcrop_api = this;
                });
            },3000);

        };
    };

    // read selected file as DataURL
    oReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

```html
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
                    <!-- hidden crop params -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="x1" name="x1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y1" name="y1" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="x2" name="x2" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="y2" name="y2" />

                    <h2>Выерьте фото</h2>
                    <div><input type="file" name="image_file" id="image_file" onchange="fileSelectHandler()" /></div>

                    <div class="error"></div>

                    <div class="step2">
                        <h2>Обрежте изображение</h2>
                        <img id="preview" />

                        <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                            <label>File size</label> <input type="text" id="filesize" name="filesize" />
                            <label>Type</label> <input type="text" id="filetype" name="filetype" />
                            <label>Image dimension</label> <input type="text" id="filedim" name="filedim" />
                            <label>W</label> <input type="text" id="w" name="w" />
                            <label>H</label> <input type="text" id="h" name="h" />
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/147614)

Comment: согласен вот код